# Whole Module Optimization and Polymorphism bug

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

A little context: we use CoreData and have `FolderEntity` and `AlbumEntity` classes that are subclasses of `NodeEntity`.  If I compile our code for debugging OR release w/Whole Module Optimization **OFF** things work as expected:

```
// fetch an entity from coreData, in this case it is a FolderEntity
// but reference it generically as a NodeEntity
if let node = context.optionalExistingObjectWithID(currentNodeID) as? NodeEntity { 
    print(node); // correctly says its a FolderEntity
    print(node.contentTypes()); // correctly calls FolderEntity.contentTypes()

    if let folder = node as? FolderEntity {
        print(folder.contentTypes()); // correctly calls FolderEntity.contentTypes()
    }
```

Things also work as expected above if I turn **ON** Whole Module Optimization and compile for *debugging*.  But if I turn **ON** Whole Module Optimization and compile for *release* polymorphism goes haywire

```
// fetch an entity from coreData, in this case it is a FolderEntity
// but reference it generically as a NodeEntity
if let node = context.optionalExistingObjectWithID(currentNodeID) as? NodeEntity { 
    print(node); // correctly says its a FolderEntity
    print(node.contentTypes()); // incorrectly calls the superclass' NodeEntity.contentTypes()

    if let folder = node as? FolderEntity {
        print(folder.contentTypes()); // correctly calls FolderEntity.contentTypes()
    }
```

`NodeEntity` (the superclass) defines contentTypes() as

```
func contentTypes() -> [SMContentType] {
    return [];
}
```

`FolderEntity` (the subclass) defines contentTypes() as

```
override func contentTypes() -> [SMContentType] {
    return [ SMContentType.Folder, SMContentType.Album ];
}
```

Why does WMO mess up inheritance like this?

Comment: "Why" is not a real question. What kind of answer would make you happy here? Behavior that differs for a Release build is a bug. File it and move on.

Comment: "If you turn on WMO it makes X assumptions so you need to construct your classes with Y and Z in mind" would be great

Comment: Well there is no such "assumptions". Behavior that differs for a Release build is a bug. I think I said that already. And Apple wants to know about it. Tell them.

Comment: I've a similar issue with Xcode 7.1.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug. File a bug report. Your bug *may* be fixed in Xcode 7.1, so try it there (currently in beta) before filing:

> A problem that caused dynamic protocol conformance checks using as? Protocol to fail in whole optimization mode has been fixed

But definitely file if it isn't fixed. Behavior that differs for a Release build is a bug, plain and simple. You should not have to do anything special to work around it.

Comment: That sounds like my problem!

Comment: Maybe. But maybe not. :(

Comment: By the way, the phrase "turn ON Whole Module Optimization and compile for debugging" in your question makes no sense. Either Whole Module Optimization is being used _for this build_ or it is not. If you compile for debugging and whole module optimization is turned on for release builds only, it is not turned on.

Comment: I can turn "Whole Module Optimization" on/off independent of the scheme being set to "Release" or "Debug" which twiddles many other compiler flags options.   So I found it odd that WMO could be ON while the scheme was in Debug and everything worked fine, but changing to scheme to Release is what caused the issue.

Comment: You probably meant  iOS 9.1, not 7.1?

Comment: Yeah, I have numeric dyslexia. :) But actually yes I mean Xcode @MartinR

Comment: Yes, that makes more sense!